# Zapier - REST hook trigger - How do you include a variable-size array output field in the output data?

Tags: zapier

For the Zapier App that I am developing, I am configuring a Trigger of type REST Hook.

Say that my API posts details about soccer matches. The format of the data that gets posted to Zapier by my API would look something like this:

```
[{
"game_start_time": "2020-06-26",
"home_score": 2,
"away_score": 1,
"goals": [
   {
      "time": "45+2",
      "player_name": "Lionel Messi",
      "team": "home"
   },
   {
      "time": "65",
      "player_name":"Cristiano Ronaldo",
      "team": "away"
   },
   {
      "time": "90+5",
      "player_name": "Lionel Messi",
      "team": "home"
   }
],
"attendance": 76000,
"penalties": [
   {
      "time": "21",
      "player_name":"Cristiano Ronaldo",
      "type": "yellow",
      "reason": "diving" 
   }
]
}]
```

The output fields are specified as follows:

- "Key": "Label"
- game_start_time: Key Start Time
- home_score: Home Score
- away_score: Away Score
- goals: Goals
- goals[]time: Goal - Time
- goals[]player_name: Goal - Player Name
- goals[]team: Goal - Team
- attendance: Attendance
- penalties: Penalties
- penalties[]time: Penalty - Time
- penalties[]player_name: Penalty - Player Name
- penalties[]type: Penalty - Type
- penalties[]reason: Penalty - Reason

I want to be able to allow a user of my App to consume all the output fields available from my API, including `goals` and `penalties`. When I try to specify these output fields, there doesn't seem to be a way for me to get the objects in the array separately.

For example:

- Expected:

```
goals: [{
      "time": "45+2",
      "player_name": "Lionel Messi",
      "team": "home"
   },
   {
      "time": "65",
      "player_name":"Cristiano Ronaldo",
      "team": "away"
   },
   {
      "time": "90+5",
      "player_name": "Lionel Messi",
      "team": "home"
   }]
```

- Actual:

```
goals[]time: "45+2, 65, 90+5"
goals[]player_name: "Lionel Messi, Cristiano Ronaldo, Lionel Messi"
goals[]team: "home, away, home"
```

It seems that it would be difficult for a Zap using my Zapier App Trigger to consume `penalties` and `goals` unless they add their own custom code to parse my Trigger's data.

Comment: Could you share how you are specifying these output fields right now?

Comment: @will-yama I have updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky situation, I believe it's related to how Zapier handles responses with nested arrays (AKA "line items" on our platform) within Zapier as a whole. That is, it's not really specific to your app/integration, per se.

By default, each key/value will get turned into a field. Any key which has an array of objects will give back individual fields as "line items" which is why you see the comma-separated values for things like goals[]Time and so on.

As it is right now, You can use a Line Item to Text Formatter step as outlined at https://zapier.com/help/create/format/get-started-with-formatter

But in this case, I'd recommend transforming the Goals and Penalties array into a top-level array with all of the data flattened within it and added to the object that the trigger is sending to the action step. You will need to do this when handling the results from the trigger as part of your dev app.

Comment: I see. For my use case, it is important to have the context of each penalty and goal (ie. Lionel Messi scored at 45+2 minutes). 

I'm not 100% sure what is meant by "top-level array with all of the data flattened".

What I have done is added new fields to the object that the trigger is sending. One called goals_JSON which is just JSON.stringify(goals), and a similar field called penalties_JSON. Using a Code By Zapier step, the data can be formatted however the user wants. It works for now, but it's hard to expect our customers to do this.